# Regex to remove parenthesis

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'd like to know if there is a way to remove **parenthesis and the content** inside a String (let's say, do this in Notepad++).

For example, I have a line like this with song titles:

```
Green Day - Basket Case (live)
ATB - Ecstasy (feat. Zara)
ATB - Behind (radio remix)
```

I'd like to execute a "Find & Replace" and have something like this:

```
Green Day - Basket Case
ATB - Ecstasy
ATB - Behind
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Find : `\s*\([^)]*\)`

Replace : `empty string`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/47

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried to used the software "Bulk Rename Utility" to see if I could use the same Regex to rename the files, but I got this problem --> http://s24.postimg.org/4in1tidz9/image.jpg -- I replaced with the char "a" just to use as a test.

Comment: @sanjuro8998 havent used that before .try `\s*\([^)]+\)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that this may help you: "\(.*\)". If you are using linux AMD you want to rename files you can do:

rename -v 's/\(.*\)//' *

On the folder that the files are.

If you are using vim and want to make the replacement on a list:

:%s/\(.*\)//g

Comment: `(.*)` matches any text.

Comment: Hi, Mariano, the editor removed the backslashes before parentesis, sorry  \\(.*\\).

Comment: for someone who doesn't know basic regular expressions, I don't think such a terse answer will be of any help. Besides, your answer doesn't remove anything, it simply matches a range of characters inside parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I'm new here and I'm trying to improve my answers, I thought that he needed just the match. I'll try to make it better next time.